# Although use of "guard let", "not unwrapped" error

Tags: swift

I have *"Value of optional Type “AnyObject?” not unwrapped did you mean to use ! or?"* error on the line `guard let tableauDeux =`

```
func attraperJSON() -> String? {

guard let krakenURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR") else {
    print("Probleme adresse")
    return nil
}
guard let tickerData = NSData(contentsOfURL: krakenURL) else {
    print("Problème ticker data")
    return nil
}
do {
    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(tickerData, options: [])
    guard let tableauUn = json["result"] else {return nil }
    guard let tableauDeux = tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"] else { return nil}
    let prix = tableauDeux["o"]
    return prix
    } catch {
    return nil
}
}
```

I don't get why the guard let doesn't work, thanks !
P.S : I know it's swift 2 and not 3 here, but i'm still working with xcode 7

Comment: First of all, use native Swift types (`URL`, `Data` and `JSONSerialization`). Secondly, check the types of your variables using Xcode to see what is the type of each of your variables. You should cast `json` to ` [String:Any]` for sure instead of parsing it as `AnyObject`.

Comment: Check the error message and see the types (Option Click on the variable). The errors are not with because of optionals instead they are for wrong types.

Comment: @user1046037 tableauUn ist `AnyObject?` so i need to unwrapped it with guard let, no ?

Comment: @DávidPásztor you mean `let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(tickerData, options: []) as! [String:Any]`?

Comment: see the answer, but the answer is in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to optional downcast all dictionaries to the proper type

```
guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(tickerData, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] else { return nil }
guard let tableauUn = json["result"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {return nil }
guard let tableauDeux = tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"] as? [String:AnyObject] else { return nil}
```

and the final value

```
let prix = tableauDeux["o"] as? String
```

Comment: Not really a topic to discuss here but I appreciate your comment - I'd be really interested in learning more about why that is.

Comment: @vadian thanks, straight to the point and  it works ! I tried `guard let tableauDeux = tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"] as? [String:String] else { return nil}` and no cast for the line after, why it doesn't work ? Thanks !

Comment: @Sparky For example the type of `tableauDeux` is supposed to be `[String:AnyObject]` but you are annotating `String`. This is a mistake. You should avoid such unnecessary mistakes. And in the `NSURL` line you can clearly see that it is `NSURL`. The annotation is redundant.

Comment: @TmSmth It doesn't work because the value of `tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"]` is `[String:AnyObject]` rather than `[String:String]`. Most of the dictionary values are arrays.

Comment: @vadian Oh yes i just check the url and even if for key "o" it's only a string, for others it's array, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

## Overview:

- Compilation Error messages states that the types are wrong
- As @David had stated try to use native types as much as possible and use `NS` counterparts only when absolutely necessary

## Code:

**The code below is in `Swift 3` on `Xcode 8`. If you are using an older version, make the necessary changes.**

```
func attraperJSON() -> String? {
    
    //Use URL instead of NSURL
    guard let krakenURL = URL(string: "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR") else {
        
        print("Probleme adresse")
        return nil
    }
    
    guard let tickerData = NSData(contentsOf: krakenURL) else {
    
        print("Problème ticker data")
        return nil
    }
    do {
        //Use "as?" to convert to desired type
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: tickerData as Data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
        
        //Use "as?" to convert to desired type
        guard let tableauUn = json?["result"] as? [String : Any],
            let tableauDeux = tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"] as? [String : String] else {
                return nil
        }
        
        let prix = tableauDeux["o"]
        return prix
    
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI In Swift 4, JSON parsing gets better with `Codable`.

Comment: You are supposed to use Data instead of NSData in Swift 3

Comment: `Data` doesn't have the option to read the contents of a file, hence the usage of `NSData` - `NSData(contentsOf: krakenURL)`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested already in the comments, I think you need to be much more explicit on your types here. I know the compiler doesn't require you to do this, but i find it helps both with my thinking and avoids the compiler getting confused if I am always fully explicit. Remember in your case the function needs to return a String, not AnyObject, so you need to make sure you have a String. So my version of your function (and I have made some assumptions on the types, but hopefully you get the gist) would be as follows:

```
func attraperJSON() -> String? {

    guard let krakenURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/.   Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR") else {
        print("Probleme adresse")
        return nil
}

guard let tickerData ; NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: krakenURL) else {
        print("Problème ticker data")
        return nil
}

do {
        if let json : [String : AnyObject] = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(tickerData, options: []) as? [String : AnyObject] {
            guard let tableauUn : [String : AnyObject] = json["result"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return nil }
            guard let tableauDeux : [String : String] = tableauUn["XXBTZEUR"] as? [String : String] else { return nil }
            let prix : String = tableauDeux["o"]
            return prix
    } catch let retrievalError {

        print("Error in \(#function): \(retrievalError.localizedDescription)")
        // please put error handling code here
        return nil
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't annotate types the compiler can infer. You make it worse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i would like to avoid "if let". @vadian what do you mean by annotate type ?

Comment: @TmSmth Annotating a type is the colon and the type after a variable name in a `let` or `var` expression before the equal sign. Basically type annotations are only necessary in a very few cases if the compiler can't infer the types and will complain.